# .net project package could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, hangfire

I'm getting the following error which states that the extension method to add hangfire does not exist:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS1061 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddHangefire' and no accessible extension method 'AddHangefire' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is my program.cs:

```
using Hangfire;
using Hangfire.SqlServer;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddHangefire();

var app = builder.Build();
```

I installed the packages but the function didn't read it.

Comment: AddHangefire is a typo. It should be `AddHangfire`?

Answer (score 0):

Add the package:

> HangFire.AspNetCore

And you have to pass the Action into the constructor for the extension method is defined as below:

[image]

Comment: Thank for your answer , where i can find the class ?

Comment: @Suliman Almula  Sorry,I forgot to mention:Add the package :HangFire.AspNetCore